# Book request: systematics and evolution of vertebrates

Tags: evolution, book-recommendation

Would you recommend any good vertebrate systematics & evolution book?

The main goal is to teach a Master's level class - mostly focused on amphibia, reptiles and fish.

Comment: I'm tempted to recommend Alfred Romer's _The Vertebrate Body_ , but it's quite out of date now.

Comment: If nobody is able to offer recommendation on Biology.SE, you can look at reviews on [Amazon by search Vertebrates Evolution](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=vertebrate+evolution). [This book](https://www.amazon.com/Vertebrates-Comparative-Anatomy-Function-Evolution/dp/0078023025/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1501610103&sr=8-1&keywords=vertebrate+evolution) has many good reviews for example

Answer (score 1):

I really like Liem et al.'s [*Functional Anatomy of the Vertebrates: An Evolutionary Perspective.*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0030223695)